# Whats a good architecture for a life simulator

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, architecture, parallel-processing

I was thinking the other day about creating a little life simulator. I have only brushed over the idea and I was wondering the best way to implement so it will run efficiently.

At the lowest level there will be male and female entities wondering around and when they meet they will produce offspring.

I would like to use multithreading to manage the entities but im not sure of number of threads etc.

Would it be best to have a couple of threads that manage males and females, or would it be ok to start a thread for each entity so each instance is running on its own thread?

I have read a few posts about maximum number of threads and the limit ranges from 20-1000 threads in an app.

Anyone have any suggestions on architecture?

N

Comment: Have you considered arbitary threadpools and the C#4 Parallel library?

Comment: I have not heard of arbitary thread pools, what are those? just a normla thread pool? I have not looked into parallel computing as yet, are there any good resources?

Comment: Resources : [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/01/parallel-programming-in-net-framework-4-getting-started.aspx) and [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). By Arbitary thread pools I mean use abstraction libaries that handle threads for you. They pool n (10, 20, 100) threads and delegate tasks to any threads which have resources available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**DO NOT HAVE ONE THREAD PER ENTITY**. That is a recipe for disaster. That is not what threads were designed for.  Threads are extremely heavyweight; remember, every thread consumes one million bytes of virtual address space *immediately*.  Also, remember that every time two threads interact on a shared data structure -- like your simulated world -- they need to take out locks to prevent corruption. Your program will be a *mass* of hundreds of blocked threads, and blocked threads are useless; they can't work. High contention is anathema to good performance, and lots of threads sharing one data structure is nothing but constant contention.

The number of threads in your program should be **one** unless you have an extremely good reason to have two. In general the number of threads in a program should be *as small as you can possibly make it while still getting the performance characteristics you need.*

If your program really is "embarrassingly parallel" -- that is, it is extremely easy to do calculations in parallel without locking a shared data structure -- then the correct number of threads is equal to the number of processor cores in the machine. Remember, *threads slow each other down*. If you have four bank tellers, and each one is servicing one customer, things go fast. You are describing a situation where you have four bank tellers (CPU cores) each servicing a hundred people *at the same time* by handing out pennies round-robin.

Simulations are rarely embarrassingly parallel because it is hard to break up the work into *independent* parts. Ray tracing, for example, is embarrassingly parallel; the contents of one pixel do not depend on the contents of any other pixel, so they can be calculated in parallel. But you would not have one thread per pixel!  You'd have one thread per processor, and let each of four processors work on a quarter of the pixels. It's hard to do that with simulations because the entities *do* interact with each other.

High quality professional simulators such as physics engines that need to deal with interacting entities do not solve their problems with threads. Typically they'll have one thread doing the simulation and one thread running the user interface, so that a costly simulation calculation does not hang the UI.

The right architecture for you is probably to have one thread going like blazes just doing the simulation. Work out *all* the interactions of the entities for a single frame and then signal the UI thread that it needs to update. This will allow you to figure out what your maximum frame rate is, by measuring how many microseconds it takes to work out all the interactions of every entity.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, that has given me a perfect understanding of the 'why' not to use many threads and is the answer I was hoping for. Ill start off with two threads and possibly expand later too add two more threads if the processor is quad core. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Using 100s of Threads (that would Sleep() a lot) is not a good solution. You will quickly run out of memory.

The TPL might make this idea workable but it wasn't really designed for this either.

Look into Discrete Event Simulation and Fibers. There are pseudo-Fiber libraries for .NET

Comment: thanks for your response, I have not heard about Event Simulation and Fibres before so Ill definately take a read, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your application manages the timeline in delta-Ts.

You could use C# 4.0's parallel framework and work with TASKs not threads.

Each delta-T run a parallel-for to update the entities.

The parallel framework will decide how many threads to open and manage the threads.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have not had any prior experience with Tasks so Ill take a look, I wanted to use something new to create this.